# Get an instance of activity that starts another from intent

Tags: android

Is there a way to get an instance of the activity that has called the currently running activity from the intent object that has been passed to it?
eg. if A has called B, I would like to retrieve A's instance from the intent in B's onCreate method.
As Activity is not Serializable i am not able to pass the instance in the extras bundle.
Any help on this would be great

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, and poses security risk, the intent can be fired by a 3rd party application and this way you get access to it.

Why do you want to do that? Just pass as Extras the variables you need, or create a reduced class to hold your data you want to transfer.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your reply. The data I want to pass contains a Socket instance which is not Serializable and so cannot be passed as extras.
Also I changed my code a bit and now want to pass this data to a Service when it is started from an activity. Is there any other way to get this Socket instance?

Answer (score 0):

a general note on passing datan between activities: If the object you want to pass along (I guess you could write a wrapper if you can't modify the actual Class) implements Parcelable - then you can pass it between activities as well. I had to do something like this recently and I wrote a few lines on [how to get going with parcelable](http://fastvergessen.blogspot.com/search/label/Parcelable). Hope it helps,

Cheers